# Access cannot close after 100s of function calls - Recordset sees to be "open" although closed

Tags: function, ms-access, median

I need to calculate roughly 100 medians in an access database and have a function (see code below)

After calling this many times with the code

```
Nz(DMedian("Price", "Qry91_Cad_by", "[Cad ID]='" & rst![Cad ID] & "'"), 0)
```

I cannot quit Access any more and need to kill it with the task manager (as there are open connections)

When compacting the database, I get the error "You attemted to open a database that is already open by user 'Admin' .....
You can close the database but Access itself needs to be killed

Any Ideas what's wrong?

...

```
Public Function DMedian( _
 ByVal strField As String, ByVal strDomain As String, _
 Optional ByVal strCriteria As String) As Variant

    ' Purpose:
    '     To calculate the median value
    '     for a field in a table or query.
    ' In:
    '     strField: the field.
    '     strDomain: the table or query.
    '     strCriteria: an optional WHERE clause to
    '                  apply to the table or query.
    ' Out:
    '     Return value: the median, if successful;
    '                   Otherwise, an Error value.

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rstDomain As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim varMedian As Variant
    Dim intFieldType As Integer
    Dim intRecords As Integer
    
    Const errAppTypeError = 3169
    
    'On Error GoTo HandleErr

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    ' Initialize return value.
    varMedian = Null
    
    ' Build SQL string for recordset.
    strSQL = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strDomain
    
    ' Only use a WHERE clause if one is passed in.
    If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strCriteria
    End If
    
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY " & strField
    
    Set rstDomain = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    ' Check the data type of the median field.
    intFieldType = rstDomain.Fields(strField).Type
    Select Case intFieldType
    Case dbByte, dbInteger, dbLong, _
      dbCurrency, dbSingle, dbDouble, dbDate
        ' Numeric field.
        If Not rstDomain.EOF Then
            rstDomain.MoveLast
            intRecords = rstDomain.RecordCount
            ' Start from the first record.
            rstDomain.MoveFirst
    
            If (intRecords Mod 2) = 0 Then
                ' Even number of records.
                ' No middle record, so move to the
                ' record right before the middle.
                rstDomain.Move ((intRecords \ 2) - 1)
                varMedian = rstDomain.Fields(strField)
                ' Now move to the next record, the
                ' one right after the middle.
                rstDomain.MoveNext
                ' And average the two values.
                varMedian = _
                  (varMedian + rstDomain.Fields(strField)) / 2
                ' Make sure you return a date, even when
                ' averaging two dates.
                If intFieldType = dbDate And Not IsNull(varMedian) Then
                    varMedian = CDate(varMedian)
                End If
            Else
                ' Odd number or records.
                ' Move to the middle record and return its value.
                rstDomain.Move ((intRecords \ 2))
                varMedian = rstDomain.Fields(strField)
            End If
        Else
            ' No records; return Null.
            varMedian = Null
        End If
    Case Else
        ' Non-numeric field; so raise an app error.
        Err.Raise errAppTypeError
    End Select

    DMedian = varMedian
    
ExitHere:
    'On Error Resume Next
    rstDomain.Close
    Set rstDomain = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

HandleErr:
    ' Return an error value.
    DMedian = CVErr(Err.Number)
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

...

Comment: I can't replicate this. Even 1000 calls don't fail. But start by removing `db.Close`. Then look elsewhere. If still no joy, test with my `DMedian` function found at [VBA.Quartiles](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Quartiles).

Comment: Wonder if this is related to recent Access bug. See if this sounds familiar: https://youtu.be/zPC0dhgVYeg

Comment: This sounds exactly like the behaviour I am experiencing - thank s- so it's an access bug

VBA.Quartiles is no Access VBA code, is it?
And the db.close was introduce to have the code not crashing earlier